# apt install failed with unmet dependencies

Tags: release-odin

I have eOS 6 and is trying to install the virt-view software. The `apt install virt-view` command failed with the following dependencies error:

```
$ apt install virt-viewer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 elementary-tweaks : Depends: libgranite5 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 virt-viewer : Depends: libgovirt2 (>= 0.3.4) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 (>= 0.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libspice-client-glib-2.0-8 (>= 0.35) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libspice-client-gtk-3.0-5 (>= 0.32) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libvirt-glib-1.0-0 (>= 0.1.8) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libvirt0 (>= 1.2.8~rc2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `apt --fix-broken install` but that didn't fix the issue. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you with the `elementary-tweaks` issue, it won't work on Odin, you'll have to install `pantheon-tweaks`.
Here you can find how to install it:
https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks

Comment: Thank you. The `pantheon-tweaks` package works.